# regexp-isearch with fixed prefix

Tags: regular-expressions, isearch

I'd like to search a buffer for headlines only. A headline is anything starting with the "`*`" character. Ideally, I'd invoke an interactive function which would take user input at the minibuffer. I'd only give it the string I'd like to search for (for example `foo`) and not worry about the regex (which would be the headline prefix `"^\*.* "` + `foo`). The function should behave the same as the classic `regexp-isearch` : reading input from the minibuffer, and search for next occurrence if you invoke it again.

Any ideas how I could do this?

**EDIT**

I found this code here. I edited it like this :

```
(defun search-headings ()
  "search for selected text"
  (interactive)
  (isearch-mode t t) ; forward + REGEXP
  (isearch-yank-string "^\*.* " ))
```

When I call search-headings the minibuffer shows a modified version of my regex, instead of `"^\*.* "`it shows `"\^\*\.\* "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two minor points to begin with:

1. You forgot to escape your backslash — `"^\\*.* "`.
2. `"^\\*.* "` should probably be `"^\\*[^ ]* "`.

`isearch-yank-string` will `regexp-quote` the string if `isearch-regexp` is non-nil.  Here is its implementation in my Emacs:

```lisp
(defun isearch-yank-string (string)
  "Pull STRING into search string."
  ;; Downcase the string if not supposed to case-fold yanked strings.
  (if (and isearch-case-fold-search
           (eq 'not-yanks search-upper-case))
      (setq string (downcase string)))
  (if isearch-regexp (setq string (regexp-quote string)))
  ;; Don't move cursor in reverse search.
  (setq isearch-yank-flag t)
  (isearch-process-search-string
   string (mapconcat 'isearch-text-char-description string "")))
```

We can implement a “literal” variation of it ourselves:

```lisp
(defun isearch-yank-string-literal (string)
  "Pull STRING literally into search string."
  ;; Don't move cursor in reverse search.
  (setq isearch-yank-flag t)
  (isearch-process-search-string
   string (mapconcat 'isearch-text-char-description string "")))
```

Your function now becomes:

```lisp
(defun search-headings ()
  "search for selected text"
  (interactive)
  (isearch-mode t t) ; forward + REGEXP
  (isearch-yank-string-literal "^\\*[^ ]* "))
```

---

If you us [Isearch Plus](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus), there is `isearchp-regexp-quote-yank-flag` which control the quoting behavior.  You can simply let-bind it to nil before calling `isearch-yank-string`.